# How would I set different id for each li element?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Good day!! My issue is this...

I sent an ajax request to get some details at the backend. After splitting the response i have 2 different arrays set to a variable.

I.e **allQst** [1,2,3,4,5,6] and **attempted** [1,2,3,4].

I now looped allQst with foreach and created an li element to list each at the frontend which works fine. The issue now is trying to add a different id for each li that would be listed.

I tried to add .attr() to the li as in,

```
<li>bla bla...</li>.html(item).attr("id","listing"+item);
```

This gives it the same id.

I also tried to make it

```
<li>bla bla...</li>.html(item).attr('id', function(i) { return 'listing'+(i+1); });
```

Doesn't work.

This is my code in full...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#next,#prev").one('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'done.php',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response) {
            var rsp = response.r2;
            var rspB = response.r1;
            var allQst = rsp.split(",");
            var attempted = rspB.split(",");
            attempted.forEach(func2);
            allQst.forEach(func);

            function func(item, index) {
                var ul = $("#list");
                var li = $('<li  class="pagination-link"></li>').html(item).attr('id', function(i) {
                    return 'listing' + (i + 1);
                });
                ul.append(li);
            }

            function func2(item, index) {
                $("#" + item).addClass("is-current");
            }
        } //succes func end
    }); //ajax end
}); //click func end
        }); //doc end
```

What I want to achieve lastly is to get the id and add a class to each of them.

I would be glad if you can assist me!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your code to use some sensible indention (tabs/spaces). It's pretty hard to follow the code and see what belongs to which code block when it's all left aligned like that.

Comment: What bou now!!! @magnus

Comment: Have you tried using `.attr('id', 'listing' + index)` instead? The `index` variable should already be different on each iteration while `i` won't be.

Comment: Yes and when I tried to put  ```var output= $("li").attr("id");
alert(output);``` inside the loop. It comes out with all the six li's having same id. I.e **listing0**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const list = $("#list");
function func(item, i) {
    let li = $(`<li  class="pagination-link">${item}</li>`).attr('id', `listing${i}`);
    list.append(li)
}
```